# Why is warning CA2214 not resolved when a sealed override method is generic?

Tags: c#, generics, code-analysis

Given the following class heirarchy:

```
class Base
{
    protected virtual void Do(int value)
    {
    }
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
    sealed protected override void Do(int value)
    {
        base.Do(value);
    }
}

class Derived2 : Derived1
{
    public Derived2()
    {
        Do(999);
    }
}
```

... the code analysis warning [CA2214](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx) is resolved by simply adding the `sealed` keyword to `Derived1.Do()`. So far, so good.

Now let's make `Do()` generic:

```
class Base
{
    protected virtual void Do<T>(T value)
    {
    }
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
    sealed protected override void Do<T>(T value)
    {
        base.Do(value);
    }
}

class Derived2 : Derived1
{
    public Derived2()
    {
        Do(999);
    }
}
```

The CA2214 warning returns. Why?

The description of the warning cites the following call stack to review:

```
Derived2..ctor()
Base.Do<T>(T):Void
```

...even though a breakpoint on `Derived1.Do()` is hit just fine.

Note: this is the case with both .NET 4.5 and 4.6

Comment: See also https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1090.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule implementation does not implement parameter matching logic that recognizes invocations of methods with generic parameters.  This is most likely a flaw in the rule implementation, as opposed to an intentional exclusion of generic methods from the sealing solution.  You may want to consider suppressing the violation as a false positive.  However, that suppression would cause a potential future unsealing of the method to go undetected, so YMMV...