# Warning about calling overridable auto-property when using generics

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, inheritance, code-analysis

Consider the following hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Base<T>
{
    protected abstract T N { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Intermediate<T> : Base<T>
{
    protected override T N { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Intermediate<int>
{
    public Derived() { N = 1; }
    protected override sealed int N { get; set; }
}
```

Running the Visual Studio 2015 Professional Code Analysis produces the warning

```
Warning CA2214  'Derived.Derived()' contains a call chain that results in a call to a virtual method defined by the class. Review the following call stack for unintended consequences: 

Derived..ctor()
Base<T>.set_N(T):Void
```

This is similar to [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018569/accessing-an-implemented-abstract-property-in-the-constructor-causes-ca2214-do), yet different as the property in `Derived` has been marked as `sealed`.

On the other hand, the piece of code below, not using any generics, does *not* produce any warnings:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract int N { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Intermediate : Base
{
    protected override int N { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Intermediate
{
    public Derived() { N = 1; }
    protected override sealed int N { get; set; }
}
```

Similarly, if I skip the intermediate class and instead derive `Derived` from `Base`, the warning disappears, even in the generic case. On the other hand, if I remove the `sealed` modifier for the latter example, the warning reappears, as expected.

So, is this working as intended in the generic case? And if so, what is an example where one should be careful?

Comment: interesting... can't explain but want to insist that it's "generics", not "templates".... c++ templates are very different from c# generics.

Comment: Thanks; let me update the wording.

Comment: Similar question, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125773/why-is-warning-ca2214-not-resolved-when-a-sealed-override-method-is-generic/32143332

Comment: @JohnKoerner: Thanks for the reference. Looks like it really is a false positive then.

Comment: GitHub issue for this query: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1090